# Azure DevOps - how to track planned vs unplanned work items

Tags: azure-devops, metrics, agile, issue-tracking

We have agile / devops culture -based teams who have a need to track work that has been planned and prioritized at an expected pace, vs work that came in for immediate handling. Some are bugs, some are tasks, some stories, etc.

We're thinking that adding a custom field is the way to go, with potential values of Maintenance and Enhancement. And of course, the hardest part: What would the field name be?

Is there a better approach? We don't think that a new work item is really it, but we could be convinced otherwise.

Additionally, we've looked at all of the canned fields and don't see an obvious field that fits, but we would prefer to use the built-in fields where it makes sense.

What, if any, is the recommended approach? I'd be very surprised if we're the first with this need.

Answer (score 1):

A custom field doesn't have big difference from predefined field, so you can feel free to create one when no existing predefined fields can meet your needs.

I agree with your thought of adding a custom field. As for the field name, we can simply name it `PlanStatus`,`PlannedOrNot` or whatever you like...

You only need:

1.One inherited process based on Agile process template.

2.Edit `Bug` type and create the field.

[image]

[image]

Then edit other workItem types who also need this field. (Edit=>Add an existing field=>PlanStatus)

3.Then you can create a bug/epic with PlanStatus field and you can use the newly created field in Query. Besides, you can add a widget in `Project OverView=>Dashboard` to track the planned/unplanned workitems. (Chart for WorkItems widget or Query Results widget or what...)